# Binding JSON data in UI5 table

Tags: json, sapui5

I"m trying to show some JSON data into UI5. I'm able to load the data and is also able to access it to show in independent fields. For ex, if I'm trying to show the data in a text view I'm able to show it. But it does not seem to work in case of a table.

Below is how I'm trying to do it(done in ajax success handler method):

```
var oModel1 = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();  
var aData = jsonModel.getProperty("{/list}");
oModel1.setData({modelData : aData}); 
weatherTable.setModel(oModel1);  
weatherTable.bindRows("/modelData");  
weatherTable.placeAt('content');
```

Updating the complete code within the script tag of index.html which shows what is jsonModel & it is not null.

```
<script>


            var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/group?id=524901,703448,2643743&units=metric";

            jQuery.ajax({
                url : url,
                dataType : "json",
                success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                    var jsonModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
                    alert("status: " +textStatus);
                    alert(data);
                    jsonModel.setData(data);
                    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(jsonModel);


                    var weatherTable = new sap.ui.table.Table({
                        title : "Current Weather Details",
                        visibleRowCount : 4             
                    });



                    weatherTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
                            label : new sap.ui.commons.Label({text : "Country"}),               
                            template : new sap.ui.commons.TextView().bindText("country")                
                    }));

                    weatherTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
                        label : new sap.ui.commons.Label({text : "City"}),              
                        template : new sap.ui.commons.TextView().bindText("sunrise")
                    }));

                    weatherTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
                        label : new sap.ui.commons.Label({text : "Weather"}),               
                        template : new sap.ui.commons.TextView().bindText("sunset")
                    }));


                    //Create a model and bind the table rows to this model    
                    var oModel1 = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();  
                    //Get the forecastday array table from txt_forecast object    
                    //var aData = jsonModel.getProperty("{/sys}");
                    alert(jsonModel);
                    var aData = jsonModel.getProperty("{/list}");                        
                    //alert(aData);
                    oModel1.setData({modelData : aData});            
                    //oModel1.setData(data);
                    alert(oModel1.getJSON());
                    weatherTable.setModel(oModel1);  
                    weatherTable.bindAggregation("rows","/modelData");  
                    weatherTable.placeAt('content'); 


                    var dataLayout = new sap.ui.layout.HorizontalLayout({
                        id : "dataLayout", // sap.ui.core.ID                
                    });

                    var country = new sap.ui.commons.TextView({
                        id : "country",
                        //text : '{/sys/country}'
                        text : '{/list/0/sys/country}'
                    })

                    var city = new sap.ui.commons.TextView({
                        id : "city", // sap.ui.core.ID
                        //text : '{/name}', // string
                        text : '{/list/0/name}', // string
                    });

                    var weatherDesc = new sap.ui.commons.TextView({
                        id : "weather", // sap.ui.core.ID
                        //text : '{/weather/0/description}', // string
                        text : '{/list/0/weather/0/description}', // string
                    });

                    dataLayout.addContent(country);
                    dataLayout.addContent(city);
                    dataLayout.addContent(weatherDesc);
                    dataLayout.placeAt("content");


                }
            });

</script>
```

When I alert aData, I get it as null as getProperty on the model is not returning anything. That's where the problem is. May be the way I'm trying to access the list is wrong.

Below is the JSON data returned:

```
{
  "cnt": 3,
  "list": [
    {
      "coord": {
        "lon": 37.62,
        "lat": 55.75
      },
      "sys": {
        "type": 1,
        "id": 7323,
        "message": 0.0208,
        "country": "RU",
        "sunrise": 1407202987,
        "sunset": 1407259673
      },
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 800,
          "main": "Clear",
          "description": "Sky is Clear",
          "icon": "01n"
        }
      ],
      "main": {
        "temp": 18.76,
        "pressure": 1019,
        "humidity": 72,
        "temp_min": 17.5,
        "temp_max": 20
      },
      "wind": {
        "speed": 3,
        "deg": 30
      },
      "clouds": {
        "all": 0
      },
      "dt": 1407200467,
      "id": 524901,
      "name": "Moscow"
    },
    {
      "coord": {
        "lon": 30.52,
        "lat": 50.43
      },
      "sys": {
        "type": 1,
        "id": 7348,
        "message": 0.0346,
        "country": "UA",
        "sunrise": 1407205931,
        "sunset": 1407260136
      },
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 800,
          "main": "Clear",
          "description": "Sky is Clear",
          "icon": "01n"
        }
      ],
      "main": {
        "temp": 19.55,
        "pressure": 1013,
        "humidity": 88,
        "temp_min": 17,
        "temp_max": 21
      },
      "wind": {
        "speed": 4,
        "deg": 10
      },
      "clouds": {
        "all": 0
      },
      "dt": 1407200377,
      "id": 703448,
      "name": "Kiev"
    },
    {
      "coord": {
        "lon": -0.13,
        "lat": 51.51
      },
      "sys": {
        "type": 1,
        "id": 5091,
        "message": 0.1124,
        "country": "GB",
        "sunrise": 1407213071,
        "sunset": 1407267704
      },
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 800,
          "main": "Clear",
          "description": "Sky is Clear",
          "icon": "01n"
        }
      ],
      "main": {
        "temp": 14.51,
        "pressure": 1018,
        "humidity": 72,
        "temp_min": 13,
        "temp_max": 17
      },
      "wind": {
        "speed": 4.1,
        "deg": 240
      },
      "clouds": {
        "all": 0
      },
      "dt": 1407200474,
      "id": 2643743,
      "name": "London"
    }
  ]
}
```

Please suggest. Awaiting your responses.

Cheers,
AW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update answer after reviewing your complete code:

1. There should be no curly brace when calling getProperty method of JSONModel.

   `var aData = jsonModel.getProperty("/list")`;
2. The binding path of your Table columns are wrong. Add **sys** path

   ```
          var weatherTable = new sap.ui.table.Table({
                   title : "Current Weather Details",
                   visibleRowCount : 4             
          });



          weatherTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
                   label : new sap.ui.commons.Label({text : "Name"}),               
               template : new sap.ui.commons.TextView().bindText("name")                
           }));

           weatherTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
                   label : new sap.ui.commons.Label({text : "Country"}),               
               template : new sap.ui.commons.TextView().bindText("sys/country")                
           }));

           weatherTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
               label : new sap.ui.commons.Label({text : "City"}),              
               template : new sap.ui.commons.TextView().bindText("sys/sunrise")
           }));

           weatherTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
               label : new sap.ui.commons.Label({text : "Weather"}),               
               template : new sap.ui.commons.TextView().bindText("sys/sunset")
           }));

           weatherTable.addColumn(new sap.ui.table.Column({
          label : new sap.ui.commons.Label({text : "Description"}),               
                 template : new sap.ui.commons.TextView().bindText("weather/0/description")
   }));
   ```

Comment: I think I"m doing the same thing as you except setting data in the set data method rather than the constructor for jsonmodel. jsonModel contains the whole data set returned from the url & there is another model created which is oModel1 which just contains the data set for the table. Please see my updated complete code which shows this and suggest. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks Allen, it works. Can you please also tell I'm trying to access the description property under the weather array. How can I access that? I've trying to use /weather. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi, glad to help, please mark my answer as answered. The description property under weather should be /list/0/weather/0/description.

Comment: Hello Allen,Surely would mark it as answered once I clear all the queries. For weather as you mentioned it will get me the description of the array element at the 0th index. As you would see my code, I'm trying to put them in the table and would like it to loop through the array so that I can get the description for each array object. Please suggest. Thanks, AW

Comment: Hi, please see my updated answer. Just add additional column templates. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Allen, it works. I dont understand one thing. For getting the description, you pointed out the path as "weather/0/description". Even after specifying the 0th element in the path how does it loops through the others as well?

Comment: Hi, as there is only one object in "Weather" child array. See， weather": [
{
"id": 800,
"main": "Clear",
"description": "Sky is Clear",
"icon": "01n"
}
].

Answer (score 0):

In your code as you mentioned that `aData` is getting `null`. I think this is because of `var aData = jsonModel.getProperty("{/list}");` here what is `jsonModel` is the question. Are trying to get the model which you set somewhere

**Example:**

```
sap.ui.getCore().setModel('jsonModel' , jsonData);  // Setting the model in core with name jsonModel
```

and get this model in a variable.

```
var jsonModel = sap.ui.getCore().getModel('jsonModel');
var aData = jsonModel.getProperty('/list'); //please check the path
```

Comment: jsonModel is not null which I've checked. I've posted the complete code within script tag. I've also posted the JSON response so that you can suggest if I'm using the wrong path or not. Please have a look and suggest.

Comment: @user3905218 : What is jsonModel in This var aData = jsonModel.getProperty("{/list}");

Comment: Please see the updated code where jsonModel is defined as the base model for the data loaded from the public webservice.